# Remove dict element from list of dicts using lambda

Tags: python, lambda

New to python here:

I'm trying to create a new list where every dict from initial list has an element removed, it exists:

```
arraylist = [{"x":1, "y":2}, {"x":3, "y":2}, {"x":5, "y":2}, {"x":33, "y":2}, {"x":1, "y":8}]
arraylist = map(lambda d: del d["y"] if "y" in d, arraylist)
```

I know I can do it using **for**, **using** del. But I'm looking to learn something new.

Comment: Using `lambda` like this is not Pythonic, only use `lambda` when you need an anonymous function (like as a key for sorting)

Comment: @Chris_Rands Why is using lambda with map fundamentally different from using lambda with sort?

Comment: @koalo A list comprehension is nearly always slightly faster (and more readable) than `map` with `lambda`, but you can't use a comprehension as a key for `sorted()`

Comment: @Chris_Rands I accept the speed argument (though I have not verified it), but the readability depends on your taste and background

Answer (score 5):

Use a list comprehension:

```
In [26]: [{x:d[x] for x in d if x != 'y'} for d in arraylist]
Out[26]: [{'x': 1}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 5}, {'x': 33}, {'x': 1}]
```

Comment: what happens if there are many other element in each dict? they get removed.

Comment: @AlexandruRada No, as a mater of fact this code doesn't do a removing it just doesn't insert invalid items. So if you have multiple invalid keys you can just change your condition to `if x not in list_of_invalid_keys`

Comment: ok, you're right. In a production system you know exactly what should be in there.

Comment: that would actually return empty dicts also. This will make the work: `[{x:d[x]} for d in arraylist for x in d if x != 'y']`

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter like this

```
arraylist = [{"x":1, "y":2}, {"x":3, "y":2}, {"x":5, "y":2}, {"x":33, "y":2}, {"x":1, "y":8}]
arraylist = map(lambda d: dict(filter(lambda (k,v): k != "y", d.iteritems())), arraylist)
```

Comment: This seems to fail with `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` pointing at the first parenthesis of `lambda (k,v)` with latest Python 3.9.5. Is this maybe Python 2 code only ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `del` in a `lambda` function because `del` is a statement and a `lambda`'s body can only be a single expression. You can't put a statement inside an expression. You could make it work with an ordinary function:

```
def delete_y(d):
    if "y" in d:
        del d['y']
    return d
```

Note that using `del` like this modifies the dictionary `d` in place. This means that returning the modified dictionary (and using the return value to build a new list) is sort of redundant. The original data structure the dictionary came from will already have the modified version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its not the shortest way, but it is definitely a convenient way to remove 
items from a list:

```
arraylist = [{"x":1, "y":2}, {"x":3, "y":2}, {"x":5, "y":2}, {"x":33, "y":2}, {"x":1, "y":8}]

print arraylist

def containsY(d):
    if 'y' in d.keys():
        del d['y']
        return True
    return False

filter(containsY, arraylist)

print arraylist
```

output:

```
[{'y': 2, 'x': 1}, {'y': 2, 'x': 3}, {'y': 2, 'x': 5}, {'y': 2, 'x': 33}, {'y': 8, 'x': 1}]
[{'x': 1}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 5}, {'x': 33}, {'x': 1}]
```

Comment: Why does your `containsY` return something?

Comment: You'er right, it does not have to return anything, but `filter` suppose to use methods with a returned Boolean value, so I just wanted to do it "by the book"

Comment: Throwing away the result of `filter` really isn't "by the book", though.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything: Using latest Python 3.9.5, the second line of output is identical to the first. Is this maybe Python 2 code only ?